# tail: troll: file truncated

Tags: code-golf, string, file-system, bash

## Background

When you run `tail -f file` in bash, the file is outputted and then any subsequent appends.

However, when you remove something that has already been displayed, `tail` outputs:

```
tail: nameoffile: file truncated
```

## Your Challenge

When given an input `f`, append `tail: [value of f]: file truncated` (with trailing & leading newline) to the file `f`. You can assume that file `f` exists, the device is not full, `f` is not empty, and that you have permissions to write to `f`.

## Test Cases

Input: `something`

File before:

```
Some
thing
```

File after:

```
Some
thing
tail: something: file truncated
```

Input `relative/path/to/file`

File before:

```
tail: relative/path/to/file: file truncated
```

File after:

```
tail: relative/path/to/file: file truncated
tail: relative/path/to/file: file truncated
```

## Reference Implementation (Node.js)

```
x=>require("fs").appendFileSync(x,`
tail: ${x}: file truncated
`)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but it doesn't seem too complicated to me.

Comment: I'm not sure your "Reference Implementation" would count as a valid answer. You need to require `fs`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 4̴0̴ 4̴6̴ 33 bytes

```bash
echo tail: $1: file truncated>>$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcsxCoQwEIXhfk4xiBewDRJQ0NZiW5tsnJiATpY4nj@rhSLY/fC@9zWbz5msjygmLArLSqELC6Gkna0RmrQuq3wU1nU39KhRaJOTwCeuBOIDz3AsAL8UWBwWLbmYSI1cwPm7PTz7wiM3Tii9dP4D)

Thanks @DigitalTrauma for `-7` bytes!

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - 33 bytes

```
.w%"\ntail: %s: file truncated"QQ
```

Comment: Can't you remove `"QQ`?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer no, because then `.w` would write to `o.txt`

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 61 bytes

```
f=input();open(f,"a").write("\ntail: %s: file truncated\n"%f)
```

<s>Can't really try it online...</s> [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY7BCsIwEETv@YolUEhQevFW6UEP/YpcUrtpA3Fb0i3Fr69RqtaD7mEYhmXmDTfuejosDkrwNEystBBPk4Jgr3VjC3BCzJ476Ack5fYg553UYEeoCgHpqnyOnlHJOtgO3mKoDviwWzGEbTtK/VW5LRuiJ1byjK6PWKTHT1jlEW2jtF5cucIeVyZppX5RGGLrQwHZmNB9QOA40cUyNoZk5vTyf9nQyTHGX9OdvwM)

Comment: Edit Request: [Change TIO link](https://tio.run/##fY7BCsIwEETv@YolUEhQevFW6UEP/YpcUrtpA3Fb0i3Fr69RqtaD7mEYhmXmDTfuejosDkrwNEystBBPk4Jgr3VjC3BCzJ476Ack5fYg553UYEeoCgHpqnyOnlHJOtgO3mKoDviwWzGEbTtK/VW5LRuiJ1byjK6PWKTHT1jlEW2jtF5cucIeVyZppX5RGGLrQwHZmNB9QOA40cUyNoZk5vTyf9nQyTHGX9OdvwM) <-- This version makes the input work with the header/footer example code.

Comment: Seems like you don't need the first `\n`, that would make your solution shorter and correct.

Comment: with python2: [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##fU7LCoMwELznK5YFaULFQ48WC@3Br/AS60YD6SpxRfr11pbSx6HdwzDMLDMzXKXrebc4KMDzMIk2Sj3IKgR7qRubg1Nq9tJBPxBrlwLOWzRgRyhzBeuV2Ry9kMY62A5eUHEd6E4/oWJq2xHNV@Rn2BA9i8YTuT5Svj6@xTKLZBttzOKK59j9wzkcntPQokmxYrE@5JCM63YfCCROfLZCDSZu@d9b8dEJxV/Fm85vbg)

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 47 bytes

```
@echo(>>%1
@echo tail: %~1: file truncated>>%1
```

Assuming DOS newlines are acceptable on Windows...